# SQL Server Full-text search for keywords without prefix matching

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, full-text-search

I have the following text in my `NVARCHAR` column

> "Ich bin eine SuperbProdukt"

I have a full-text search enabled on the column and I can search for it by executing the following query that I wrote :

```
SELECT FROM MY_TABLE WHERE CONTAINS(Title, ' "Ich*" ')
```

The query gives me all the result that contains my search criteria, I can also search for other words within the whole text such as "`Superb`" and get the same record back. However, I am trying to have a search functionality that returns results even when I give keywords that are not the **beginning** of any words in a phrase, but rather it's in **between**. For instance, I am expecting to get the same record back when searching for "`Produkt`"

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL server **without** using `LIKE` operation? I heard that `CharIndex` can do the job, but I have no clue how that can be helpful in my scenario.

P.S: I am using **SQL SERVER 2012 on Azure.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to achieve what you described using [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). 
According to this [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks):

> If CHARINDEX does not find expressionToFind within expressionToSearch,
>   CHARINDEX returns 0.

Knowing that you just have to filter the rows like this:

```
DECLARE @expressionToFind varchar(50)  = 'an';

SELECT MiddleName
FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Person
WHERE CHARINDEX(@expressionToFind, MiddleName, 1) <> 0;
```

Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see, it brings not only the middle names that begin with **an** but also the ones with **an** in the middle of the text.

A little remark regarding this method is that **differently** from using the Full-Text Search it will scan your table. It might (and almost certainly will) have a big performance impact.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.